# Most standard compliant database

Tags: php, sql, database, compatibility

Im thinking about databases to use as a development environment for a cross platform php application.

What im ideally looking for is a database that supports the most correct standards of SQL, something i can write for and hopefully guarantee cross database compatibility when it comes to deployment.

I'd prefer it if it was open source.

Thanks

Comment: I am using [PosgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/), it is SQL compliant, has a powerful support to functions and triggers, an optimized engine for text search, is very robust and the best of all: is free.

Comment: I got a 1UP, I got a satisfying answer, and i accepted it as the solution. soooo... why was this closed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There really isn't such a thing - there is no "cross-platform SQL".

The SQL standards and specifications are very outdated and haven't kept in-step with advances with RDBMS systems, but also because different engines implement their own features (such as geospatial indexing and resultset paging) differently.

The best way to write a cross-platform application is to abstract away database-specific operations to a "data access layer" and implement this interface for each database backend you plan to support.

If you're doing very trivial operations such as SELECT (with simple joins), INSERT and UPDATE then you might get away with using a single set of SQL commands, assuming you don't run into issues with syntax or data-types (for example, JET Red/Access requires all dates to be delimited with `#` but T-SQL (SQL Server, Sybase) require single-quotes; or how MySQL uses backticks to escape names but T-SQL and JET Red uses `[]` square brackets. Also, each implementation has its own set of keywords).

Comment: If this is the case, then i will target MySql due to it being the most popular open source and free database, although i'll try to stick to standards as much as possible. thanks

Comment: I would recommend implementing PDO to act as your DAL http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php, using it to run your queries through. See http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/ for some justifications. (But why reinvent the wheel, right?)

Comment: Also see: http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799

Answer (score 1):

**MySql** Why ?

> **MySQL** :: The world's most popular open source database
>   (RDBMS)[6] as of 2008 that runs as a server providing multi-user access to a number of databases.

Features

As of April 2009, MySQL offered MySQL 5.1 in two different variants: the open source MySQL Community Server and the commercial Enterprise Server. MySQL 5.5 is offered under the same licences.[32] They have a common code base and include the following features:
**A broad subset of ANSI SQL 99, as well as extensions**

1. **Cross-platform support**
2. Stored procedures
3. Triggers
4. Cursors
5. Updatable
6. Views
7. Information schema
8. Transactions with the InnoDB, and Cluster storage engines;
   savepoints with InnoDB
9. SSL support

& so many ...
[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL#Features)

or little one & faster **postgres**
Also Why ?

because it is **PostgreSQL: The world's most advanced open source database**

- open-source
- Object-Relational DBMS supporting almost all SQL
- constructs
- including subselects
- transactions
- and user-defined
  types and ..
  & it is used on **android** ;) 
  www.postgresql.org